# Solving this $4$ variable diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is there a way to solve this Diophantine equation in $a,b,c,d$? $$19a^3-33a^2b+3a^2c+30a^2d+21ab^2+24abc-12abd-15ac^2-54acd-30ad^2+ $$ $$2b^3-12b^2c-6b^2d+42bc^2+108bcd+60bd^2-7c^3-51c^2d-99cd^2-56d^3=0$$

Wolfram Alpha unfortunately cannot understand my input whenever I input this equation, and I know no strategy to solve these kinds of equations. So basically, I'm stuck...

---

I want just all possible values for $a,b,c,d$ just like what Wolfram Alpha does.

**Note:** $a\neq b\neq c\neq d\neq 0$

Comment: did you try to group by factorization and simplify the structure ?

Comment: @G Cab Um... No? Is that possible?

Comment: what produced this polynomial? Where did you get it, exactly?

Comment: oh, well. If it factors, it is a homogeneous linear times a quadratic form. If the quadratic form is definite, the set of solutions is an integral lattice. Just one possibility.

Comment: It doesn't factor.

Comment: by factoring/simplify I mean if it is coming from some simple combination of a few $(x*a+y*b+z*c+w*d)^3$: so can we know the generating mechanism of such a homogeneous polynomial as already asked?

Comment: Write another equation - when can not be reduced to the sum of the cubes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is homogeneous of degree $3$, so if $(a,b,c,d)$ is a solution so is $(ta,tb,tc,td)$ for any $t$.  Thus it makes sense to look for **primitive** solutions, which are solutions with greatest common divisor $1$.  I found some $288$ primitive solutions with $a,b,c \in [-20\ldots -1, 1\ldots 20]$ and $d \in [1 \ldots 20]$.  I don't see an obvious pattern.
Here are some of those solutions:

$$ \matrix{ a & b & c & d\cr
-4 & -1 & -8 & 1\cr
-4 & 1 & -8 & 3\cr
-3 & 1 & -7 & 3\cr
-3 & 1 & 3 & 1\cr
-3 & 5 & -1 & 4\cr
-2 & 1 & -6 & 3\cr
-2 & 1 & -4 & 2\cr
-2 & 2 & -4 & 3\cr
-2 & 3 & -4 & 4\cr
-2 & 3 & 2 & 1\cr
-2 & 4 & -4 & 5\cr
-2 & 5 & -4 & 6\cr
-1 & -1 & -5 & 4\cr
-1 & 1 & -5 & 3\cr
-1 & 2 & -3 & 3\cr
-1 & 5 & 1 & 1\cr
1 & -2 & -1 & 2\cr
1 & -1 & -5 & 2\cr
1 & 1 & -3 & 3\cr
1 & 2 & -7 & 6\cr
2 & 1 & -2 & 3\cr
2 & 2 & 4 & 1\cr
2 & 3 & 4 & 2\cr
2 & 4 & 4 & 3\cr
2 & 5 & 4 & 4\cr
2 & 6 & 4 & 5\cr
3 & -4 & -7 & 1\cr
3 & 1 & -1 & 3\cr
3 & 2 & -5 & 6\cr
3 & 4 & -3 & 4\cr
4 & 3 & 8 & 1\cr
5 & 1 & 1 & 3\cr
5 & 2 & -3 & 6\cr
6 & 1 & 2 & 3\cr
7 & 1 & 3 & 3\cr
7 & 2 & -1 & 6\cr
8 & 1 & 4 & 3\cr
}$$

Did those coefficients come from somewhere in particular or are they just arbitrary?

Comment: Robert, could it be the determinant of a 3 by 3 matrix with entries linear forms in $a,b,c,d?$ Not sure

Comment: I don't know.  How would one check that?

Comment: Good point; it is just a possible source, the OP has not said. I do wonder whether we can join two integer solutions by a straight line and find another. Just musing.

Comment: Hey; to answer your question, yes. The coefficients do come from somewhere!

Comment: Aha! In some cases you can join two solutions by a straight line and get solutions, in others you can't.  For example,  joining solutions $(-4,-1,-8,1)$ and $(-4,1,-8,3)$ you get a one-parameter family of solutions $(-4, 1-2t, -8, 3-2t)$.  Another such family is $(2-4t, 3+t, 4-8t, 2+3t)$ from joining $(-2, 4, -4, 5)$ and $(2, 3, 4, 2)$.

Comment: Robert, thanks for checking.

Comment: In many cases, it seems that a two-dimensional cross-section of this cubic variety is an elliptic curve.  The rational points on this elliptic curve form a group (and suitable multiples of them are then integer solutions).

Comment: @RobertIsrael: The substitution $a=u+v,\;c=-u+v$ reduces the OP's cubic equation to just a quadratic in $v$. Its discriminant is a quartic polynomial to be made a square, hence an elliptic curve is involved as you pointed out.

Comment: I do not understand. Why subscribe to these figures? Write parameterization solutions!

Comment: @individ OK, be my guest: parametrize all the solutions.

Comment: Okay, @TitoPiezasIII Does this help: $$(a+2c-2b+3d)^3+(2a-b+2c+4d)^3=(a+b+2c+2d)^3+(3a-2b+c+3d)^3$$Using other random Diophantine equations, I have found one: $$16^3+2^3=15^3+9^3=4101$$ and using another one, I got: $$32^3+4^3=30^3+18^3=32832$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael: With this update by the OP, it seems the equation does have a complete solution (by Euler). See my answer below. Which is strange since I thought the elliptic curve would allow infinitely many parameterizations.

Answer (score 3):

As the OP pointed out in the comments that the equation is equivalent to,

$$(a + 2c - 2b + 3d)^3 + (2a - b + 2c + 4d)^3 - (a + b + 2c + 2d)^3 - (3a - 2b+ c + 3d)^3 = 0$$

then by equating terms, its complete solution is,

$$\begin{aligned}
a= -2 x_1 - 7 x_2 - 5 x_3 - 8 x_4\\
b=-6 x_1 + 5 x_2 - 2 x_3 + 2 x_4\\
c=9 x_1 - 14 x_2 - 10 x_3 - 3 x_4\\
d=-5 x_1 + 15 x_2 + 7 x_3 + 6 x_4
\end{aligned}$$

where,

$$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3 = 0$$

The complete rational solution by Euler is well-known.

Comment: You wouldn't mind if you proved your formula: $n^3+(3n^2+2n+1)^3+(3n^3+3n^2+2n)^3=(3n^3+3n^2+2n+1)^3$? I read that in a pdf document you wrote and I'm interested to see your proof...

Comment: I'm wondering where did you get the starting grouped-equivalent from: I do not see any in the post, nor I got any reply to my comment asking exactly about that. Do you have a priviliged channel? or is it my browser's problem?

Comment: @GCab No, I don't think the equation can be factored into your form.

Comment: @Frank: That formula in $n$? With elementary identities, the most direct way is just to expand and compare both sides.

Comment: @GCab: The OP  remarked about the $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3=0$ form in [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945775/solving-this-4-variable-diophantine-equation/1946416?noredirect=1#comment3996025_1945798).